# Replace None values in Pandas Using more than two columns

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a sample dataset (actual one is huge and over 100 columns) for simplicity;

```
temp2 = pd.DataFrame({'DNB_Match':[None,'match',None,'match','nomatch',None],'country':['US','NZ','CA','PH',\
None,'IN'], 'BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN':['True','False','True','False','False','False']})
```

The goal is to impute the None values in the column DNB_Match using following logic

- If `BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN=True` and `country`=`US` then DNB_Match should be `US-Missing`
- If `BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN=False` then DNB_Match should be `Not Applicable`
- If `BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN=True` and `country`!=`US` then DNB_Match should be `Missing`

Here is my code;

```
 temp2['DNB_Match'].apply(lambda row:'US-Missing' if (row['DNB_Match'] is None and row['BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN']=='True' \
                            and row['country']=='US') \
                            else('Not-needed' if (row['DNB_Match'] is None and row['BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN']=='False') \
                                else ('Missing' if (row['DNB_Match']  is None and row['BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN']=='True' and row['country']!='US') 
                                     else row['DNB_Match'])))
```

But it gives following error;

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I understand that we can't subscript a `None` object, but I am not aware of any other way on how to iterate over rows and fetch values from other columns ( by name). Since actual data has hundreds of columns, it will be better to fetch values by labels rather than indices. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't nee to do a loop nor do you have to do apply. You can get the result by using the following three conditions.

```
import pandas as pd
temp2 = pd.DataFrame({'DNB_Match':[None,'match',None,'match','nomatch',None],
                      'country':['US','NZ','CA','PH',None,'IN'],
        'BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN':['True','False','True','False','False','False']})

print (temp2)
temp2.loc[(temp2.country == 'US') & (temp2.BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN=='True'),'DNB_Match_New'] = 'US-Missing'
temp2.loc[(temp2.country != 'US') & (temp2.BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN=='True'),'DNB_Match_New'] = 'Missing'
temp2.loc[(temp2.BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN=='False'),'DNB_Match_New'] = 'Not Applicable'

print (temp2)
```

The output of this will be:

```
  DNB_Match country BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN   DNB_Match_New
0      None      US                True      US-Missing
1     match      NZ               False  Not Applicable
2      None      CA                True         Missing
3     match      PH               False  Not Applicable
4   nomatch    None               False  Not Applicable
5      None      IN               False  Not Applicable
```

If you want to make the change directly to DNB_Match, then you can do it as follows:

```
temp2.loc[(temp2.country == 'US') & (temp2.BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN=='True'),'DNB_Match'] = 'US-Missing'
temp2.loc[(temp2.country != 'US') & (temp2.BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN=='True'),'DNB_Match'] = 'Missing'
temp2.loc[(temp2.BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN=='False'),'DNB_Match'] = 'Not Applicable'
```

Output will be:

```
        DNB_Match country BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN
0      US-Missing      US                True
1  Not Applicable      NZ               False
2         Missing      CA                True
3  Not Applicable      PH               False
4  Not Applicable    None               False
5  Not Applicable      IN               False
```

And if you want to change only values that have `None` and do not want to disturb any value that's got `match` or `nomatch`, then you can give it like this:

```
temp2.loc[(temp2.country == 'US') & (temp2.BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN=='True') & (temp2.DNB_Match.isnull()),'DNB_Match'] = 'US-Missing'
temp2.loc[(temp2.country != 'US') & (temp2.BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN=='True') & (temp2.DNB_Match.isnull()),'DNB_Match'] = 'Missing'
temp2.loc[(temp2.BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN=='False') & (temp2.DNB_Match.isnull()),'DNB_Match'] = 'Not Applicable'
```

The output of this will be:

```
        DNB_Match country BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN
0      US-Missing      US                True
1           match      NZ               False
2         Missing      CA                True
3           match      PH               False
4         nomatch    None               False
5  Not Applicable      IN               False
```

It retains the `match` for `NZ` and `PH` and `nomatch` for `None` which changing only values for `US`, `CA` and `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me

```py
temp2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "DNB_Match": [None, "match", None, "match", "nomatch", None],
        "country": ["US", "NZ", "CA", "PH", None, "IN"],
        "BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN": ["True", "False", "True", "False", "False", "False"],
    }
)

def foo(e):
    if e["DNB_Match"] is not None:
        return e
    
    if not e["BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN"] == "True":
        e["DNB_Match"] = "Not Applicable"

    if all([e["country"] == "US", e["BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN"] == "True"]):
        e["DNB_Match"] = 'US-Missing'

    if all([not e["country"] == "US", e["BUSINESS_INFO_GIVEN"] == "True"]):
        e["DNB_Match"] = "Missing"

    return e


temp2.apply(lambda e: foo(e), axis=1)
temp2
```

Comment: checking for None should be `e['DNB_Match'].isnull()` or `e['DNB_Match'].notnull()`

Comment: @JoeFerndz Yes it is. But it seems that the None value is added by hand, not the pandas's NaN value. So I am not using it in the case.

Comment: pandas will still detect None as null as long as None is not in quotes